# imagefill only filling half the image background?

Tags: php, image

imagefill is only filling half the image background?

Anyone got any ideas?

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng($current);
$kek=imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($img,0,0,$kek);
imagejpeg($img,$new,70);
imagedestroy($img);
```

[image: Example]
[image: Example]

Comment: have you tried `imagepng($img);` ?

Comment: I have not but thank you for the 'keyword', I will investigate!

Answer (score 0):

imagefill perform a Flood-Fill algorithm to the image, same as bucket fill in paint does. so filling continues until the area is closed, and filling will be stopped. 
You should copy original image into larger canvas, then perform an imagefill, then crop the image agian to get back to original size:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng($current);
$width=imagesx($img);
$height=imagesy($img);
$newimg=imagecreatetruecolor($width+2,$height+2);//1 pixcel larger from each side
imagecopy($newimg,$img,1,1,0,0,$width,$height);
$kek=imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($img,0,0,$kek);
imagecopy($img,$newimg,0,0,1,1,$width-2,$height-2);//back to the original size
imagejpeg($img,$new,70);
```

I didn't test the code, but I think it should be OK.